# is.null function does not identify NULL values

Tags: r, isnull

I want to calculate the logarithm of total assets, and I want r to set the result to NULL if the total assets element itself is 0. Otherwise, r will show me -Inf as the result.
I have tried to solve this problem as follows:

```
at <- c(0.028, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
name <- c("comp 1","comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(name, at)) 
df$log_at <- ifelse(is.null(at),  0, log(at))
```

However, if you run this line of code, the column 2 with the log(assets) will then show -3.575551 instead of 0 in each row of the data frame for the NULL values of the total assets. Also, I wanted to know how many NULL values are in the total assets column, but:

```
sum(is.null(df$at))
```

will give me 0, so I am wondering why r does not identify the Null values as such, since the values in the total assets column are all numeric.

I know, I can use the following as an alternative since the amounts of total assets are pretty big but I am wondering why the code above does not work.

```
df$at <- as.numeric(df$at)
df$log_at <-  log(df$at + 1)
```

I hope someone can help me out !

Comment: Can you `dput` your data, so we can provide you a solution? You current code works 'as intended' just not how you want it to work. You want run your codes rowwise, and this is not what you are doing.

Comment: I presume you may be looking for either `df$at == ''` or `is.na(df$at)`

Comment: I am not familiar with dput, but my dataset contains over 250000 observations with 36 variables, and has approximately 8GB, don't know if that plays a role@Serkan

Comment: We need a [mcve] please; please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for lots of suggestions about how to set up a reproducible example.

Comment: is that sufficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` is not `0`. Check:

```
is.null(df$at)
[1] FALSE
```

So if you want to transform `at`using `ifelse`then it should be:

```
df$log_at <- ifelse(at == 0,  0, log(at))
```

Likewise, to find out how often `at` is `0`:

```
sum(df$at == 0)
```